# How to enter SIM PIN with new network manager (Ubuntu 20.04.1)

Tags: nmcli, wwan

On my Ubuntu 20.04.1 tablet I try to get WWAN working.

But after insert of the SIM card, there is no prompt for the SIM PIN. Therefore, the ttyHS2 device is "not available", I assume (if this may be a different problem, please advise! :) ).

I know that network manager always was dense in asking for the SIM PIN. Therefore, I tried to do this via CLI. But the new network manager cli utility has a complete new syntax, which is why 99% of search machine founds does not help!

```
$ nmcli --version
nmcli-Werkzeug, Version 1.22.10
```

The complete man page of nmcli does not contain the phrase "pin" (as own word).
Does anyone know how this is possible??

Of course: I made thousands of restarts, reinserted the SIM card many times, enabled/disabled the whole network stuff multiple times via UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to add a connection with PIN with the following commands:

```
mmcli -i 0 –-pin '<PIN_HERE>'
sudo nmcli con add type gsm ifname <IF_HERE> con-name <NAME_HERE> apn '<APN_HERE>'
nmcli r wwan on
```

This works both in Debian 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Worth trying on your version, too.
Take care to enter correctly the first command (`mmcli`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer - this sounds promising! I don't have the SIM card anymore, as this was a temporary business card. But nevertheless your answer may help others!

Comment: In case you like it and find that it works, please accept it as the answer for your question! ;) Thanks!